# Add bar to bottom of point plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a point plot and I wanted to add a bar to the bottom of a point plot. I can't seem to find out how to do this in the ggplot documentation. I was hoping to add at bar the spanned the entire x-axis with a set y-axis value. Here is an example of the data I am working with

```
d=data.frame(drink=c("coffee","tea","water"), mean=c(5,6,9), lower=c(4.5,5.6,8.7), upper=c(5.5,6.3,9.5))
```

and here is the code I am using

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_errorbar(data=d, mapping=aes(x=drink, ymin=upper, ymax=lower), width=0.2, size=1, color="blue") + 
  geom_point(data=d, mapping=aes(x=drink, y=mean), size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10) + ylim(0, 12)
```

Here is what the plot currently looks like

[image]

and this is what I want to add

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `annotate()` function allows you to directly specify a layer without intermediate data.frame. In ggplot2, the `-Inf`/`Inf` values for continuous variables indicate to place something at the extremes.

```r
library(ggplot2)

d=data.frame(drink=c("coffee","tea","water"), 
             mean=c(5,6,9), 
             lower=c(4.5,5.6,8.7), 
             upper=c(5.5,6.3,9.5))

ggplot(d) + 
  geom_errorbar(
    mapping=aes(x=drink, ymin=upper, ymax=lower), 
    width=0.2, size=1, color="blue") + 
  geom_point(
    mapping=aes(x=drink, y=mean), 
    size=4, shape=21, fill="white") +
  scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 12)) +
  annotate("rect", xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = 1, fill = "black")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a pattern?

Comment: You can have a look at the [ggpattern](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/index.html) package, but I'm not extremely familiar with it.

Comment: I was looking at it and it doesn't look like you can but I was just curious if you knew a work around